# Rasterise a point pattern in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, lidr, terra, spatstat

I have a set of georeferenced points within an area for which I want to know the spatial distribution (sparse/clustered) according to a regular grid.
I thought to describe the pattern using the Clark-Evans index (from `spatstat.core` package) so that I get a single value describing it...and this could be spatialised within the whole study area through a raster (I know that aggregation is scale-dependent but that's also part of the research interest).

Unfortunately, I can't achieve the rasterization process in a "smooth" way with `R`. The two approaches which I though of look something like:

```
my_fun = function(x,y){
         out = spatstat.core::clarkevans(spatstat.geom::ppp(x,y,window = ?))
         return(out)
         }


terra::rasterize(data, myraster, fun=my_fun)
```

or

```
lidR::pixel_metrics(data, fun=my_fun(X,Y), res=1)
```

Both approaches lack of a fondamental parameter: the `window`...and indeed points are dropped. `ppp` objects need a `owin` object which, in this case, it would be constituted by the pixel boundaries. But how can I provide a window at that stage? I guess creating a method?

Right now I'm using a pretty time-consuming workaround such as:

- convert raster pixels to polygons
- loop the aggregation function through each polygon/window
- revert back to raster making use of `X,Y` from the centroid and the index value I get.

Any smooth solution or methodological alternative?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "windows"? I do not understand what is the role of the polygon in this story. Can you draw a picture of what you want to to?

Comment: If I understand what you are wanting to do, calculate a PPA on a lidar point cloud given each pixel, this is an incorrect application of a point pattern statistics. In a planar context the statistic would be fairly irrelevant in indicating a spatial process and with the 3D nature of lidar data any PPA would be completely invalid (the CSR null does not hold).

Comment: @JRR In point-pattern analysis, the "window" is the area over which the process generating the point pattern is defined. ie its anywhere you might find a point from a realisation of the process. eg if you have a record of all trees in a field, the window is the shape of the field.

Comment: Why do you want to put the points into a regular grid? If you are interested in if your points are clustered then use a test from spatstat that works on the point coordinates. I don't understand "according to" in "I want to know the spatial distribution (sparse/clustered) according to a regular grid"

Comment: @Spacedman I know very little about point-pattern but here what I don't understand is the distinction between raster cells size and "windows". Does OP want to compute point pattern analysis of points inside each pixel with a windows smaller than the pixel size?

Comment: @JRR to me none of this makes sense as is. you don't need to rasterize points to compute a points clustering measure. if you do rasterize it, then what? treat each grid cell with any points in it as a point and look for clustering of the cells? in which case the window is still the study area. Nope, needs more info.

Comment: Oh, is the plan to compute the clustering for all points within each grid cell? ie there's quite a few points in each grid cell, so you can get a meaningful clustering measure, then map that to look for non-stationarity across the study area? A quadrat analysis? Possibly easier to compute the grid as a bunch of polygons, then subset the points and compute the clustering coeff and reform the grid.

Comment: it seems I wasn't that clear but yes:  JRR: the idea is to compute point pattern analysis of points inside each pixel with the size of the pixel as owin window. JeffreyEvans: the interest is only related to X and Y, not Z. @Spacedman, you got the point and reached -basically- the same solution I summarised in the three bullets. My main issue is that mine (which uses a loop) takes quite long time over bigger areas...I'll test yours using sapply

Answer (score 2):

Use these packages:

```
library(spatstat)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
```

create a test data set. 1000 points in a unit square and a 5x4 grid of quadrats:

```
nx=5
ny=4
grid = raster(matrix(1:(nx*ny), ny, nx))
gridpoly = rasterToPolygons(grid)
pts = cbind(runif(1000), runif(1000))
plot(gridpoly)
points(pts)
```

[image]

Now loop over each of the `gridpoly` rows, calling the `spatstat` function by creating a `ppp` with that row as the window, and it will warn (but drop) the points outside the window. Add the CE coefficient from the `cdf` corrected version to the polygons:

```
gridpoly$CE = sapply(1:nrow(gridpoly), function(i){
    clarkevans(as.ppp(pts, W=as.owin(gridpoly[i,])))["cdf"]
})
```

and plot:

[image]

giving a map of the coefficient for the points within each grid cell.

Testing with another data set that has a grid (extreme inhibitory) of points in most of the space and some random points in one corner:

[image]

gives a coefficient map which looks right - high values for inhibitory process except in the corner which is 1 for random points:

[image]

The difference in the blue area and slight difference in the yellow area is probably down to edge correction methods (see docs for the details).

It **is** be possible to do all this within `spatstat` using a `split` PPP object. For example here's a PPP of random points in a unit square:

```
P = ppp(pts[,1],pts[,2], window=owin(c(0,1), c(0,1)))
```

and this defines a grid of 5x4 in that window:

```
Z = quadrats(P, 5,4)
```

this `Z` can then be used to split the `P` object into parts which some `spatstat` function will apply over, for example `density`:

```
D = density(split(P,Z))
```

when plotted will show 20 separate density plots in a 5x4 layout.  However a split `ppp` is also equivalent to a list, so you can apply any function over the splits:

```
CE2 = lapply(split(P,Z), clarkevans)
```

which gets you a list of `clarkevans` results:

```
$`Tile row 1, col 1`
    naive  Donnelly       cdf 
0.8908877 0.8346257 0.8620706 

$`Tile row 1, col 2`
   naive Donnelly      cdf 
1.277086 1.204744 1.217105
```

etc which you can now manipulate with the usual list manipulation tools and reform into a grid. In fact, extracting the 3rd element from each of these gives the same vector as `gridpoly$CE` above:

```
 sapply(CE2, function(c){c[3]})
Tile row 1, col 1.cdf Tile row 1, col 2.cdf Tile row 1, col 3.cdf 
            0.8620706             1.2171046             1.1047117 

> gridpoly$CE
 [1] 0.8620706 1.2171046 1.1047117 0.864[etc]
```

which is reassuring that I've got both methods right (or both wrong...)